# Load wordpress blog posts outside wordpress installation directory

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to load only some contents outside the wordpress installation directory? I'm working on a website and I want to embed some blog contents on a static `index.php` made using bootstrap4. This page is not part of the wordpress installation, so I want to understand if this is possible and how.

Comment: This is possible in many ways. You can create a JSON and call those data in new page/site. Otherwise you need to query via the `wp_post` table.

Comment: Can you show an example? I'm a newbie with wordpress...

Comment: Also check [What is the correct way to use WordPress functions outside WordPress files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/12615)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Note: change the 'path-to-wordpress' to actual wp directory path.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);
require('/path-to-wordpress/wp-load.php');

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 5 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
);
$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
  $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </li>
<?php }
}
else {
  echo '<p>There are no posts</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any link on the wordpress codex about this usage of wp? I can use all the wp functions to build custom query right?

Comment: I'm not sure this approach is mentioned in the codex.
Yes, you can use all the wp functions. wp-load.php is the access to all functions of WordPress. But `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false )` will not load the Theme files. If want to load theme files delete this line.

Comment: No, I don't care about theme files. I want to use my own markup and framework to display a post list and the post content. Once clicked, the post content can be loaded using wp query right?