# the_permalink() wordpress outside wp installation folder

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code to load wordpress posts outside the wordpress installation directory. I've found very useful my precedent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851187/load-wordpress-blog-posts-outside-wordpress-installation-directory) about and an [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101503/include-wordpress-core-into-own-scripts) topic that will discuss about this usage of the wp functions in other indipendent php pages.

PHP query

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);

require 'portfolio/wp-load.php';

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 6,
#'offset' => 0,
#'category' => 'portfolio',
#'category_name' => '',
#'orderby' => 'date',
#'order' => 'DESC',
#'include' => '', 'exclude' => '',
#'meta_key' => '',
#'meta_value' => '',
#'post_type' => 'post', 'post_mime_type' => '',
#'post_parent' => '',
#'author' => '',
#'post_status' => 'publish',
#'suppress_filters' => true
);

$portfolio_items = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

html

```
<div class="row" id="portfolioPosts">

<?php
if($portfolio_items->have_posts()):
  while($portfolio_items->have_posts()):
    $portfolio_items->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="portfolio-grid-el">
<a class="portfolio-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()):
  the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'card-img-top post-preview', 'title' => 'Feature image']);
endif;
?>
<h4 class="portfolio-post-title text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

My question is about `the_permalink()` function, how i can link it correctly, I've configured wordpress to use my website index that is an indipendent page outside the wp installation directory and in the website root. For now every time i click on the link, the address is `http://localhost:8000/mysite/post-name` so I will not be able to display the post. I want to use a solution where the `<a href="">` link is relative to the wordpress installation path or to a page that will accept the post name as an argument and load the content, as i understand by using the loop with a custom query. Is it possible?

Comment: _“For now every time i click on the link, the address is `http://localhost:8000/mysite/post-name` so I will not be able to display the post.”_ - huh, why not? That either is the URL of the post, or it isn’t. It’s an absolute URL, so it doesn’t matter where the actual link is located. Unclear what your actual problem is here. _“I've configured wordpress to use my website index that is an indipendent page outside the wp installation directory and in the website root”_ - not sure a) what that means, and b) what bearing it has on the problem. Please explain in detail.

Comment: @misorude I'm loading the posts on a section of my index. so I'm not loading wordpress from the path where is installed but I only load his core functions to display a list of posts. `the_permalink()`will link to the root of my website, so the post content will be not displayed because in the root doesn't exist the page. this because the correct path I need to obtain is `http://localhost:8000/mysite/portfolio/post-name` and not `http://localhost:8000/mysite/post-name`

Comment: `the_permalink` should link to the correct URL, no matter what. This sounds more like you messed up the configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code :

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>

<?php echo get_permalink($portfolio_items->post->ID); ?>
```

[More info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)